# Why is the dendrogram structure different from what I see of my data in a 3D PCoA?

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I conducted hierarchical clustering on a dissimilarity matrix computed from a series of species distribution models [text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BO1SixycI4wXwdXi4A3wT3HH-VZWfQus/view?usp=sharing) and I seem to get different visible structure between the dendrogram and the 3D PCoA of the data. I have tried other clustering algorithms but cannot the structure always differs from the PCoA plot. Any idea why?

The code I wrote for the dendrogram is here:

```r
overlap = read.csv(file.choose(), row.names = 1, header = TRUE)
library(dendextend)
hc <- hclust(as.dist(overlap, diag = TRUE), method= "ward.D2")
par(mar=c(4, 10, 1, 1), cex=0.8)
plot_horiz.dendrogram(hc, side=TRUE)
#abline(v=0.55, col="grey", lty=2, lwd=3)
title(main="Warren's I", xlab="Dissimilarity")
```

End result is this:

[image: dendrogram]

The 3D PCoA code is below:

```r
library(rgl)
pcoa = cmdscale(as.dist(overlap), k=3, eig=T, add = TRUE) 
         # run PCOA, add term is for negative eigenvalues
pcoa_scores = data.frame(pcoa$points) #save scores to data frame

colnames(pcoa_scores) = c("PCoA1","PCoA2", "PCoA3")

plot3d(x=pcoa_scores$PCoA1, y=pcoa_scores$PCoA2, z=pcoa_scores$PCoA3,
   xlab = "PCoA1", ylab = "PCoA2", zlab = "PCoA3",
   size = 3)
with(pcoa_scores, text3d(x=pcoa_scores$PCoA1, y=pcoa_scores$PCoA2, 
 z=pcoa_scores$PCoA3, 
     texts = str_trunc(row.names(pcoa_scores), 15)))
```

Since the 3D plot is manipulatable, I am not including an image and encourage others to play with the plot.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a lot of things I'm unfamiliar with, but a quick check, shows that the eigenvalues in your pcoa don't drop of until the last 3 or 4 of them, which means that only looking at the first 3 primary components is pretty useless as it only covers 11.4% of the datas "variance".

```r
pcoa <- cmdscale(as.dist(overlap), k = 3, eig = T, add = T)

plot(pcoa$eig)
sum(pcoa$eig[1:3])/sum(pcoa$eig)
pcoa$GOF # Goodness of fit, see here https://ichthyology.usm.edu/courses/multivariate/mar_3.pdf
```

[image]